# scrape and manipulate with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I make an ajax request to get an external page which works - but I'm unable to manipulate the pages content, I want to get a few `h2` elements and render them to a `div` on my page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'www.example.com',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        var mycontent = $(data).filter("h2");
    }
});
```

I get an error as my response contains html/header tags.

Comment: It isn't possible without either access to the server or a proxy script of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

To fetch an external file served by another domain or port and manipulate its content in a modern browser you must either

- use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
- set [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control)

In both cases that means you have access to the server.

By the way, you can't, as you seem to try, do a jsonp request and hope to have the answered content served in the success function : the server calls directly your javascript function by answering `functionName(someJson)`.

Comment: Or, setup local "proxy" for data, which may be done without access to remote resource.

Comment: If by local you mean on the server side, yes, and this may be used sometimes. But that's not really getting a resource served by another domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. AJAX is meant to handle a *request* to a page (script), along with some data; the script evaluates the data and returns a *response*.

This is not related to the contents of a normal web page, unless the server has a specific service to handle you a page's HTML.
In other words, scraping is normally not possible this way.